# Foreign key refers invalid column in referred table

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]I have a table `ClientsPurchases` with the column `BillNo`. I would like to refer BillNo column into `Payments` table as a Foreign Key, but its showing error.

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referred table.
>   'ClientsPurchases' that match the referencing column list in the
>   foreign key 'FK__Payments__BillNo__286302EC'. Msg 1750, Level 16,
>   State 0, Line 1

```
CREATE Table ClientsPurchases
(
    PurchasesId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    PurchasesDetails VARCHAR(75),
    [BillNo] varchar(75) NULL 
)

--My  Payments table as bellow 


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Payments]
(
    [PaymentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PayAmount] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [PaymentDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ClinetId] [int] NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ([BillNo])  REFERENCES ClientsPurchases(BillNo)     
)
```

Please advice.

Comment: You want to create a foreign key in table Payment on field BillNo and it should reference the field BillNo in table ClientPurchases. But in table Payments there IS NO field BillNo. That is what the error is trying to tell you

Comment: And the referenced column must be a key (primary key, or unique constraint.)

Comment: I dont have bill No Key or constraint in ClientsPurchases table; is there any way to do without declare it as key

Comment: in the create table above you have BillNo in ClientPurchases but not in Payments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[BillNo]` in your `ClientsPurchases` should be unique.

Also, I think your foreign key should be defined as a column in the `Payments` table as well:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Payments]
(
    [PaymentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PayAmount] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [PaymentDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ClinetId] [int] NULL,
    [BillNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ([BillNo])  REFERENCES ClientsPurchases(BillNo)     
)
```

More about creating foreign key constraints [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx).

Comment: this looks like the correct answer to me so I dont understand why someone downvoted it

Comment: Because that's how the Internet works. :)
Thanks for your support.

Comment: table created but not showing relationship in entity diagram

Comment: Maybe the explorer didn't refresh properly, try the following code:

`SELECT
    fk.NAME,
    OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) 'Child table',
    OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) 'Parent table',
    fk.*
FROM sys.foreign_keys fk`

Comment: I have deleted Entity Diagram and Created New; still same

Comment: Have output form your query  : 
FK__Payments__BillNo__3F466844 Payments ClientsPurchases FK__Payments__BillNo__3F466844 1061578820 NULL 1 .....

Comment: The output means the key is there in the database, it was indeed created. Don't know why it doesn't get displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118441/discussion-between-evilpenguin-and-rubel).

Comment: is there an unique constraint on the field BillNo in the ClientPurchases table ? This would be easier if you would edit your question and put the correct and updated create statements.

Comment: Developer has table e.g. `Person(id int PK, LastName varchar(250))` and the suggestion is to refer this table by `LastName`? Whilst it already has a primary key on integer column?

Comment: It seems peculiar, indeed, but it may be that in accounting the payment must be directly associated with a bill number..
What you're saying makes sense -  do the foreign key relationship on the primary key of the referenced table.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to `BillNo` because it isn't a key. You should make it `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Is NOT NULL really needed?

Comment: @jarlh, Now that you mention it, I'm not entirely sure. I think it is in combination with `unique`. It would make sense if it's a foreign key anyway

Comment: table created but not showing relationship in entity diagram

Comment: you cannot create the table Payments with that foreign key it is impossible as long as the field BillNo is not present in table Payments. Or you do not show us the complete create statement for that table

Comment: Hi Have Payment Table : CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Payments](
 [PaymentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [PayAmount] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
 [PaymentDate] [datetime] NULL,
 [ClinetId] [int] NULL,
 [BillNo] VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ([BillNo])  REFERENCES ClientsPurchases(BillNo),
 FOREIGN KEY ([ClinetId])  REFERENCES [dbo].[Clients]([ClinetId])   

)
GO